# How to modify a script from a package and still make it work?

Tags: python, package, anaconda

I've installed a package called 'prince' to use MCA (multiple correspondance analysis).

I had an issue while executing the code and I've noticed that someone else posted that issue on github and there was a merge pull request to solve that issue.

Since the installation doesn't take that into account, I tried to copy the new script inplace of the previous one and run the code but now I get this error *'attempted relative import beyond top-level package'*  from the first import which wasn't the case before even if the import was there too.

So I guess when you modify the script even a little bit there's something particular that happen's ? Maybe it's a minor thing and I could still get away with it but I don't quite understand the mechanics here, could someone help me please ?

Thanks !

(P.S : I'm using Python 3.6 on Anaconda)

EDIT : Aaron solved, in this specific case, the problem I had. That being said I'd still be interested to know how I it could be done if one notices something in the source code and wants to modify it.

Comment: link to merged code?

Comment: @Aaron https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince/tree/master/prince/plot/mpl

Comment: Try removing it, and installing latest dev version as described in the github readme. It seems like it's already been merged, but not uploaded to PyPi yet

Comment: This worked perfectly Aaron, thanks.